# EPPlus C# unable to load assembly

Tags: c#, epplus

First of all, sorry for my English.
I'm trying to make a program that changes some texts in excel files.
Everything works OK in visual studio but when I  try to run the ".Exe" it gaves me "unable to load assembly EPPlus.. And other dependencies..."

I don't know what should I do.
Is the any way to run the program without needed install epp in every machine?
Can anyone help me?

I'm not a developer I'm just trying to learn by myself and some basics things are out of my knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried change .Net 3,5 - 4 - 7,6,2,etc..
Also tried to change the epplus assembly path
Everything with no luck

Comment: Post the actual error as *text* in the question itself. The question mentions incompatible runtimes - .NET Framework 2, 3.5 and 4, .NET Core 7, 6. You can't use a .NET Framework assembly in a .NET Core project or vice versa

Comment: That solves the error!! Copying DLL and XML to the same folder was the solution!
Many thanks!

Comment: Please consider marking @Jackdaw 's answer as accepted for his effort and future reference.